# Can you set css min-width relative to another element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a nav menu of links and sub menu. I want the submenu min width to be that of the link. Is this possible in CSS? I'm using LESS if that helps at all.

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <a href="">Item FooBarBaz</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>sub1</a></li>
        <li><a>sub2</a></li>
        <li><a>sub3</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>
       <a href="">Item FooBarBazZipBamBop</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>sub1</a></li>
        <li><a>sub2</a></li>
        <li><a>sub3</a></li>
       </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I want each `ul.submenu` to have the min-width of the previous sibling anchor. Obviously this would be a potentially different value for each submenu. Is this possible in CSS? Or is jquery, javascript a better solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/SeKT9/

```
ul
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}



body > ul > li 
{
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

ul > li  a
{
    display: block;
    margin: 5px;
}

ul > li:hover > ul
{
    display: block;
}

ul > li > ul
{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    display: none;
} 

ul > li > ul > li
{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: In fact this works **only** for the OP's case (which is also a very common use case), generally I think we hardly can do the thing as mentioned in the **question title** using just CSS, what if we have another element inside each `li` like this http://jsfiddle.net/SeKT9/1/ the *This is the footer note* will determine the width of the `li` and that's also the `min-width` of the submenu **unless** the link has text longer than the *This is the footer note*.

Comment: I agree with you @KingKing you will have to create a pretty usecase specific implementation. As you know, for your example, you could just set the footer info `position: absolute;` as well: http://jsfiddle.net/NicoO/SeKT9/2/. Of curse it's not nice to have a lot of absolute elements and destroy the flow, but there are always solutions for each requirement.

Comment: @NicoO yes, we need to work around in specific cases, I just would like to mean that in CSS, `relative` almost means `relative to parent`, so if the element is not the parent, we have to find some work-around, even alter the layout ...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just adding an inline-block div around each submenu is quicker/easier?  I'm always hesitant to add many lines of code for a small simple effect.

```
<ul>
   <li>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>
        <a href="">Item FooBarBaz</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a>sub1</a></li>
            <li><a>sub2</a></li>
            <li><a>sub3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
   </li>
   <li>
    <div style='display:inline-block;'>
       <a href="">Item FooBarBazZipBamBop</a>
       <ul class="submenu">
        <li><a>sub1</a></li>
        <li><a>sub2</a></li>
        <li><a>sub3</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: extra markup and inline style rules? Thank you but that's not exactly what I was looking for.